# Replacing data in a chart with known slide index and shape_id

Tags: python-pptx

I would like to update data in a Bar chart, but I am getting error at the step of accessing the object holding the chart.  Here is code that gives me shape_id:

```
shp=prs.slides[0].shapes
for shape in shp:
    print(
        "id: %s, type: %s, name: %s"
        % (shape.shape_id, shape.shape_type, shape.name)
    )

# => **Output:** id: 7, type: CHART (3), name: Chart 6
```

But, when I try to use shape_id to define chart object, I am getting below error:
chart = prs.slides[0].shapes[7].chart

**Error:**

```
raise IndexError("shape index out of range")
IndexError: shape index out of range
```

I also tried this code: chart = shp._spTree.shape_id[7].chart

**Error:**

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the shape-id as an *index* into the shapes sequence. The shape-id does not correspond to the position of that shape in the shapes "list".

To look up a shape by id (or name) you need code like this:

```
def find_shape_by_id(shapes, shape_id):
    """Return shape by shape_id."""
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape.shape_id == shape_id:
            return shape
    return None
```

or if you doing a lot of it you can use a dict for that job:

```
shapes_by_id = dict((s.shape_id, s) for s in shapes)
```

Which then gives you all the handy `dict` methods like:

```
>>> 7 in shapes_by_id
True
>>> shapes_by_id[7]
<pptx.shapes.Shape object at 0x...>
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I used a dictionary approach, I received below output.  How can it be used to access an object? (possibly chart to update)

Comment: {4: <pptx.shapes.placeholder.SlidePlaceholder at 0x1d79990b048>,
 5: <pptx.shapes.placeholder.SlidePlaceholder at 0x1d79990b080>,
 13: <pptx.shapes.placeholder.SlidePlaceholder at 0x1d79990b0f0>,
 6: <pptx.shapes.placeholder.SlidePlaceholder at 0x1d79990b128>,
 7: <pptx.shapes.graphfrm.GraphicFrame at 0x1d79990b1d0>,
 8: <pptx.shapes.group.GroupShape at 0x1d79990b208>,
 77: <pptx.shapes.autoshape.Shape at 0x1d79990b240>}

Comment: `chart = shapes_by_id[7].chart`. The returned object is a `GraphicFrame` shape which is the _container_ of the actual chart object. The extra `.chart` is required to access the chart object within the graphic-frame container: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-graphfrm.html